# Nodejs / Express - Launching my app: express.createServer() is deprecated

Tags: javascript, node.js, mongodb, express, socket.io

I downloaded a node app to test and play around with. I have googled around and found that Express is found to be a little outdated. Can someone help me to fix the implemented code?

Here is the code

```
/**
 * Module dependencies.
 */

// base dependencies for app
var express = require('express')
  , routes = require('./routes')
  , DB = require('./accessDB').AccessDB
  , passport = require('passport')
  , mongoose = require('mongoose')
  , mongoStore = require('connect-mongodb');

var app = module.exports = express.createServer();
global.app = app;

var DB = require('./accessDB');
var conn = 'mongodb://localhost/CrowdNotes';
var db;

// SocketIO Configuration
//var io = require('socket.io').listen(app);
//
//io.sockets.on('connection', function(socket) {
//  socket.on('user note', function (note) {
//    console.log(note);
//  });
//});

// Configuration
app.configure(function(){
  app.set('views', __dirname + '/views');
  app.set('view engine', 'jade');
  app.use(express.cookieParser());
  app.use(express.bodyParser());
  app.use(express.methodOverride());
  app.use(require('stylus').middleware({ src: __dirname + '/public' }));
  app.use(express.session({ 
    store: mongoStore(conn)
  , secret: 'applecake'
  }, function() {
    app.use(app.router);
  }));
  app.use(passport.initialize());
  app.use(passport.session());
  app.use(express.static(__dirname + '/public'));
});

db = new DB.startup(conn);

app.configure('development', function(){
  app.use(express.errorHandler({ dumpExceptions: true, showStack: true })); 
});

app.configure('production', function(){
  app.use(express.errorHandler()); 
});

// Routes
require('./routes')(app);

app.listen(3000);
console.log("Express server listening on port %d in %s mode", app.address().port, app.settings.env);
```

And here is the error I receive once running the app via `node app`

```
C:\CrowdNotes>node app
Warning: express.createServer() is deprecated, express
applications no longer inherit from http.Server,
please use:

  var express = require("express");
  var app = express();


C:\CrowdNotes\app.js:63
console.log("Express server listening on port %d in %s mode", app.address().po
                                                                  ^
TypeError: Object function app(req, res){ app.handle(req, res); } has no method
'address'
    at Object.<anonymous> (C:\CrowdNotes\app.js:63:67)
    at Module._compile (module.js:449:26)
    at Object.Module._extensions..js (module.js:467:10)
    at Module.load (module.js:356:32)
    at Function.Module._load (module.js:312:12)
    at Module.runMain (module.js:492:10)
    at process.startup.processNextTick.process._tickCallback (node.js:244:9)

C:\CrowdNotes>
```

FIXED.

I am now at the point where I register, and go to login using my new 'User' data and receive this error:

```
ReferenceError: C:\CrowdNotes\views\account.jade:6
    4|   div#header 
    5|     h2 CrowdNotes
  > 6|     p Hi, #{currentUser.name.first}! 
    7| 
    8|   - if (myEvent)
    9|     p.center My Event: #{myEvent.name} 

currentUser is not defined
    at eval (eval at <anonymous> (C:\CrowdNotes\node_modules\jade\lib\jade.js:176:8))
    at exports.compile (C:\CrowdNotes\node_modules\jade\lib\jade.js:181:12)
    at Object.exports.render (C:\CrowdNotes\node_modules\jade\lib\jade.js:216:14)
    at View.exports.renderFile [as engine] (C:\CrowdNotes\node_modules\jade\lib\jade.js:243:13)
    at View.render (C:\CrowdNotes\node_modules\express\lib\view.js:75:8)
    at Function.app.render (C:\CrowdNotes\node_modules\express\lib\application.js:500:10)
    at ServerResponse.res.render (C:\CrowdNotes\node_modules\express\lib\response.js:716:7)
    at module.exports.getAccount (C:\CrowdNotes\routes\index.js:47:11)
    at Promise.module.exports.getMyEvent (C:\CrowdNotes\accessDB.js:54:7)
    at Promise.addBack (C:\CrowdNotes\node_modules\mongoose\lib\promise.js:128:8)
```

I'm wondering if this is some form of syntax error too? Not sure what's gone wrong here as I thought the code all lined up tbh.

I am using the code from here: https://github.com/rockbot/crowdnotes

Comment: Please submit another question  for another issue

Answer (score 63):

The solution is given in the error.

Warning: express.createServer() is deprecated, express
applications no longer inherit from http.Server
please use:

```
  var express = require("express");
  var app = express();
```

So you will have to just do this.

```
var express = require('express')
  , http = require('http');

var app = express(); 
var server = http.createServer(app);
```

Comment: Thanks for the reply. I have added a new error to the post above, do you have any idea why this is happening?

Comment: the error is because the template is unable to find where the object currentUser is defined

Comment: Interesting, it's pretty hard to follow the path it takes when using currentUser in this example. I for example cannot see where currentUser would next go to in terms of files.

Comment: In index.js file the function getAccount is setting the currentUser from request object .just log to see if request has user field present

Comment: I've added onto the getAccount function `if(req.user != null)` then do the function, but I don't know if this is the right way to go about it, or what to return if there is no currentUser. Sorry to pester you.

Answer (score 6):

Its can done with this simple program:

```
var express = require('express');
var app = express();
app.get('/',
    function(req,res)
    {
        res.send("express");
    }
);
app.listen(3333);
```

it works fine.

Answer (score 2):

Another potential solution to this is to install express 2.5.8 as a dependency.

Add to package.json:

```
    {
    "name": "authentication"
  , "version": "0.0.1"
  , "private": true
  , "dependencies": {
      "express": "2.5.8"
    , "jade": ">= 0.26.1"
  }
}
```

and then run

```
npm install
```

Answer (score 1):

```
var express = require('express');
var app = express();
app.listen(your_port_number);
```

With the newer release of express (express 4.x), you do not need to create server. app.listen internally does that. Refer https://expressjs.com/en/4x/api.html#app.listen

Answer (score 0):

I am already using the following snippet and it is working fine:

```
var express =require("express");
var http = require("http");

var app = express();
//app routers here 
...
var httpServer = http.Server(app);

httpServer.listen({PORT}, function(err){

});
```