# node.js express createServer() not a function

Tags: express

I'm trying to build an express project. After I npm install, create server.js and node server.js, I got this error:

```
var app = module.exports = express.createServer();                                ^
TypeError: undefined is not a function

at Object.<anonymous> (/Users/zez/Desktop/node/nodeblog/server.js:3:36)
at Module._compile (module.js:449:26)
at Object.Module._extensions..js (module.js:467:10)
at Module.load (module.js:349:32)
at Function.Module._load (module.js:305:12)
at Function.Module.runMain (module.js:490:10)
at startup (node.js:124:16)
at node.js:807:3
```

and here is my code in server.js:

```
var express = require('express');
var app = module.exports = express.createServer();                                   
app.configure(function(){
app.set('views', __dirname + '/views');
    app.set('view engine', 'jade');
    app.use(express.bodyParser());
    app.use(express.methodOverride());
    app.use(app.router);
    app.use(express.static(__dirname + '/public'));
});


app.get('/', function(req, res){
    res.render('index', {
            title: 'Express'
                });
});

app.listen(3000);
```

Answer (score 47):

Change:

```
var express = require('express');
var app = module.exports = express.createServer();
```

To:

```
var express = require('express');
var app = express();
//Middleware
app.listen(3000)
```

You can also globally install express with the following command and then automatically generate a express template with the following command:

```
npm install -g express
```

Generate template:

```
express myAppName
cd . && npm install
```

Answer (score 12):

express.createServer() has been deprecated, perhaps your project's package.json is pointing at the latest version? Try pinning it to 2.5.10 and npm install again. Or check [Nodejs / Express - Launching my app: express.createServer() is deprecated](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13499010/nodejs-express-launching-my-app-express-createserver-is-deprecated) on how to update the project to work with more recent versions of express.

Answer (score 11):

`express.createServer();` is deprecated you need to use the http one.

```
var express = require('express');
var http = require('http');
var app = express();
var server = http.createServer(app);
```