# Socket.io error hooking into express.js

Tags: javascript, node.js, express, socket.io

I'm trying to hook socket.io and express.js together:

```
var socket = require('./socket_chat/socket.js');

var express = require('express'),
    app = module.exports.app = express();

    var io = require('socket.io').listen(app);

    app.use(express.static(__dirname + '/app'));

io.sockets.on('connection', socket);
```

At the line: `var io = require('socket.io').listen(app);` I'm getting an error:

```
Error: You are trying to attach socket.io to an expressrequest handler function. Please pass a http.Server instance.
```

There doesn't seem to be anything on SO/google about this error...

Answer (score 59, accepted):

You can do it without using `http` module

app.listen return a server instance you can use for socket.io

```
const express = require('express');
const app = express();
const server = app.listen(port, () => {
    console.log("Listening on port: " + port);
});
const io = require('socket.io')(server);
```

Comment: This answer the question of why cannot the socket be established using express

Comment: This is the correct answer and is so simple. Thanks!

Answer (score 72):

You should use `http` module:

```
var http = require('http');
var express = require('express'),
    app = module.exports.app = express();

var server = http.createServer(app);
var io = require('socket.io').listen(server);  //pass a http.Server instance
server.listen(80);  //listen on port 80

//now you can use app and io
```

More details you can find in a documentation: http://socket.io/docs/#using-with-express-3/4

Comment: You the man! you saved my day. I just have to use the server.listen() instead of app.listen()

Comment: But what is the reason that we cannot use the express() instead we have to use the http module? what is the alternative to express' createServer()?

Comment: http.createServer(app) may be depreciated https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13499010/nodejs-express-launching-my-app-express-createserver-is-deprecated use @Tagada 's answer

Answer (score 3):

For socket.io to work with express, you need a server instance and therefore **attach** it to socket.io

I'll use **.listen** method of express since it returns an http.Server object. Read the docs [here](http://expressjs.com/en/api.html#app.listen)

```
const port = 3000,
      app = require('express')(),
      io = require('socket.io')();

// Your normal express routes go here...

// Launching app
const serverInstance = app.listen(port, () => {
    console.log('App running at http://localhost:' + port);
});

// Initializing socket.io
io.attach(serverInstance);
```

Comment: neat trick! takes less code than using the http / https createServer way :)

Answer (score 1):

`http` method works for me. I tried this.

```
import express from 'express'
import http from 'http'

import { Server } from 'socket.io'
const app = express()

const server = http.createServer(app)
const io = new Server(server)
server.listen(3001)
```

Answer (score 0):

[image]After a lot of searching i found a way similar to you guys:

```
//declare your app as
const app = express()

//declare a connection separately from app as
const server = http.createServer(app)

//finally declare io from server instead of app
const io = socketio(server)

//to use io inside route screens, set io inside req as
(req,res,next)=>{
  req.io=io
}
```

then use app as you wish

i got this answer from this amazing site: https://towardsdatascience.com/building-a-real-time-web-app-in-nodejs-express-with-socket-io-library-d9b50aded6e6