# nodejs EADDRINUSE error

Tags: javascript, node.js, port

I started using [cloud9][1] and trying to host my nodejs app.
When I try to run my app it is throwing me following error:

Important: use process.env.PORT as the port and process.env.IP as the host in your

```
Important: use process.env.PORT as the port and process.env.IP as the host in your scripts!                                                                            

debugger listening on port 15454                                                                                                                                       
8080                                                                                                                                                                   
0.0.0.0                                                                                                                                                                

events.js:72                                                                                                                                                           
        throw er; // Unhandled 'error' event                                                                                                                           
              ^                                                                                                                         
Error: listen EADDRINUSE                                                                                                                
    at errnoException (net.js:905:11)                                                                                                   
    at Server._listen2 (net.js:1043:14)                                                                                                 
    at listen (net.js:1065:10)                                                                                                          
    at Server.listen (net.js:1147:9)                                                                                                    
    at exports.lookup.callback (dns.js:72:18)                                                                                                                          
    at process._tickCallback (node.js:442:13)                                                                                                                          
    at Module.runMain [as _onTimeout] (module.js:499:11)                                                                                                               
    at Timer.listOnTimeout [as ontimeout] (timers.js:112:15)
```

My app.js:

```
var app = require('express')();
//var app = express();
//var http = require('http');
var server = require('http').Server(app);
var io = require('socket.io')(server);
app.set('port', process.env.PORT || 3000);
var port = app.get('port');
console.log(port);
server.listen(port, process.env.IP);
// routing
app.get('/', function (req, res) {
    res.sendfile(__dirname + '/index.html');
});
// usernames which are currently connected to the chat
var usernames = {};
// rooms which are currently available in chat
var rooms = [];
io.sockets.on('connection', function (socket) {
    socket.on('adduser', function (username, room) {
        socket.username = username;
        socket.room = room;
        usernames[username] = username;
        socket.join(room);
        socket.emit('updatechat', 'SERVER', 'You are connected. Start chatting');
        socket.broadcast.to(room).emit('updatechat', 'SERVER', username + ' has connected to this room');
    });
    socket.on('createroom', function () {
        var new_room = (""+Math.random()).substring(2,7);
        rooms.push(new_room);
        socket.emit('updatechat', 'SERVER', 'Your room is ready, invite someone using this ID:' + new_room);
        socket.emit('roomcreated', new_room);
    });
    // when the client emits 'sendchat', this listens and executes
    socket.on('sendchat', function (data) {
        // we tell the client to execute 'updatechat' with 2 parameters
        io.sockets. in (socket.room).emit('updatechat', socket.username, data);
    });

    // when the user disconnects.. perform this
    socket.on('disconnect', function () {
        // remove the username from global usernames list
        delete usernames[socket.username];
        // update list of users in chat, client-side
        io.sockets.emit('updateusers', usernames);
        // echo globally that this client has left
        if(socket.username !== undefined){
            socket.broadcast.emit('updatechat', 'SERVER', socket.username + ' has disconnected');
            socket.leave(socket.room);
        }
    });
});
```

I tried looking for any process already running at 8080, this is the output

```
user@chat_room:~/workspace (master) $ ps ax | grep node
14154 pts/1    S+     0:00 grep --color=auto node
```

If I try using other port then I am not getting socket file, it throws me 404 error:

`<script src="/socket.io/socket.io.js"></script>`

This works fine in local.

**EDIT**
Open ports:

```
user@chat_room:~/workspace (master) $ netstat --listen
Active Internet connections (only servers)
Proto Recv-Q Send-Q Local Address           Foreign Address         State      
tcp        0      0 *:mysql                 *:*                     LISTEN     
tcp        0      0 localhost:17123         *:*                     LISTEN     
tcp6       0      0 [::]:http-alt           [::]:*                  LISTEN     
tcp6       0      0 [::]:ssh                [::]:*                  LISTEN     
Active UNIX domain sockets (only servers)
Proto RefCnt Flags       Type       State         I-Node   Path
unix  2      [ ACC ]     STREAM     LISTENING     353035357 /tmp/tmux-1000/cloud91.8
unix  2      [ ACC ]     STREAM     LISTENING     351539622 /home/ubuntu/lib/mysql/socket/mysql.sock
unix  2      [ ACC ]     STREAM     LISTENING     352204732 /home/ubuntu/.c9/1312164/collab.sock


user@chat_room:~/workspace (master) $ netstat -vatn
Active Internet connections (servers and established)
Proto Recv-Q Send-Q Local Address           Foreign Address         State      
tcp        0      0 0.0.0.0:3306            0.0.0.0:*               LISTEN     
tcp        0      0 127.0.0.1:17123         0.0.0.0:*               LISTEN     
tcp        0      0 127.0.0.1:37186         127.0.0.1:15455         TIME_WAIT  
tcp        0      0 127.0.0.1:15454         127.0.0.1:59371         TIME_WAIT  
tcp6       0      0 :::8080                 :::*                    LISTEN     
tcp6       0      0 :::22                   :::*                    LISTEN     
tcp6       0    400 172.17.0.248:22         10.240.179.70:43154     ESTABLISHED


user@chat_room:~/workspace (master) $ netstat -vat
Active Internet connections (servers and established)
Proto Recv-Q Send-Q Local Address           Foreign Address         State      
tcp        0      0 *:mysql                 *:*                     LISTEN     
tcp        0      0 localhost:17123         *:*                     LISTEN     
tcp        0      0 localhost:37186         localhost:15455         TIME_WAIT  
tcp        0      0 localhost:15454         localhost:59371         TIME_WAIT  
tcp6       0      0 [::]:http-alt           [::]:*                  LISTEN     
tcp6       0      0 [::]:ssh                [::]:*                  LISTEN     
tcp6       0      0 user-chat_:ssh 10.240.179.70:43154     ESTABLISHED


user@chat_room:~/workspace (master) $ lsof -i
COMMAND     PID   USER   FD   TYPE    DEVICE SIZE/OFF NODE NAME
mysqld     2316 ubuntu   10u  IPv4 351539621      0t0  TCP *:mysql (LISTEN)
apache2    2374 ubuntu    4u  IPv6 351539675      0t0  TCP *:http-alt (LISTEN)
apache2    2381 ubuntu    4u  IPv6 351539675      0t0  TCP *:http-alt (LISTEN)
apache2    2382 ubuntu    4u  IPv6 351539675      0t0  TCP *:http-alt (LISTEN)
apache2    2383 ubuntu    4u  IPv6 351539675      0t0  TCP *:http-alt (LISTEN)
apache2    2384 ubuntu    4u  IPv6 351539675      0t0  TCP *:http-alt (LISTEN)
apache2    2385 ubuntu    4u  IPv6 351539675      0t0  TCP *:http-alt (LISTEN)
vfs-worke 13915 ubuntu   13u  IPv4 352221394      0t0  TCP localhost:17123 (LISTEN)
```

Comment: What command are you using to launch to Node.js server?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I would say the error said it all:

> Important: use process.env.PORT as the port and process.env.IP as the host in your scripts!

Your environment wants you to use `process.env.PORT` and `process.env.IP` for port and ip respectively (is that cloud9?), but on this line you're using another environmental variable:

```
app.set('port', process.env.app_port || 8080)
```

Fix:

```
app.set('port', process.env.PORT || 8080)
```

(In general, the EADDRINUSE error is for when another process is listening to that port)

**For the 404 error**

*EDIT*: the code posted before was for an old version of Express. See http://socket.io/docs/#using-with-express-3/4

Comment: Thanks, but I am getting this error:  express has no method 'createServer' According to this answer http://stackoverflow.com/a/13499302/608388 express server is deprecated.

Comment: @ntechi see http://socket.io/docs/#using-with-express-3/4 I was posting code for an old version of express

Comment: tried, still getting 404 if tried with different port and EADDRINUSE error if using `app.set('port', process.env.PORT || 3000);` My app works if I run it on other then 8080 but 404 for socket file. Please check my updated code

Comment: Can you please post the updated code? Anyways, to check which ports are in use: http://www.cyberciti.biz/faq/how-do-i-find-out-what-ports-are-listeningopen-on-my-linuxfreebsd-server/

Comment: added the outputs of open ports

Comment: I did this on remote server, I am using the cloud9 IDE and terminal from browser tool

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/71715/discussion-between-ntechi-and-qualcuno).

Comment: So finally I managed to terminate the 8080 process and everything started to work, no 404 errors also. Thank you

Answer (score 3):

Is it possible in your code that you're requesting to `listen()` to the same port at two locations in your source ? I don't see two listen calls, but I'm not that familiar with express or sockets to know if another function does this... it happened to me once though in a different situation.

Answer (score 0):

List the processes running on the port 8080 by using command:
lsof -i :8080,
By using the PID of running processes Kill the instance which uses port 8080 by using command:
kill -9 PID