# Failed at the messenger-get-started@1.0.0 start script 'node app.js

Tags: node.js, amazon-ec2, facebook-chatbot

My server works fine on local, but when I start server after dploying to amazon ec2 it throws the following error:
This solution didnt suffice for me https://github.com/fbsamples/messenger-platform-samples/issues/43

```
node dist/app.js
```

node dist/app.js

```
events.js:141
      throw er; // Unhandled 'error' event
      ^

Error: listen EADDRINUSE :::3979
    at Object.exports._errnoException (util.js:907:11)
    at exports._exceptionWithHostPort (util.js:930:20)
    at Server._listen2 (net.js:1250:14)
    at listen (net.js:1286:10)
    at Server.listen (net.js:1382:5)
    at EventEmitter.listen (/var/www/node_modules/express/lib/application.js:618:24)
    at Object.<anonymous> (/var/www/dist/app.js:120:6)
    at Module._compile (module.js:409:26)
    at Object.Module._extensions..js (module.js:416:10)
    at Module.load (module.js:343:32)

npm ERR! Linux 3.13.0-44-generic
npm ERR! argv "/usr/bin/nodejs" "/usr/bin/npm" "start"
npm ERR! node v4.8.0
npm ERR! npm  v2.15.11
npm ERR! code ELIFECYCLE
npm ERR! mychatapp@1.0.0 start: `node dist/app.js`
npm ERR! Exit status 1
npm ERR!
npm ERR! Failed at the mychatapp@1.0.0 start script 'node dist/app.js'.
npm ERR! This is most likely a problem with the mychatapp package,
npm ERR! not with npm itself.
npm ERR! Tell the author that this fails on your system:
npm ERR!     node dist/app.js
npm ERR! You can get information on how to open an issue for this project with:
npm ERR!     npm bugs mychatapp
npm ERR! Or if that isn't available, you can get their info via:
npm ERR!
npm ERR!     npm owner ls mychatapp
npm ERR! There is likely additional logging output above.
```

Suspecting not loading of process.env, I have even tried to hard code the following values, but result is the same.

```
const VALIDATION_TOKEN = '3f92bb17caf0e11f5632920a402e1687'

const PAGE_ACCESS_TOKEN = 'EAAN9j2KfDg0BAIUrb8ZCaPmgHQXyO88mR55X40gWSJ8gi0CagZC0bJ0wZCETTVFSIUHLC7Fr58O9q8JHrQYFtc1vT2ksjPxV2Z34dqZAUiZCfpyInRa24EyvZABvpK72nooh86TUCVlYn1F9njjIWlDVfvbNw481nZCvOOW0T5EOZAQZDZD'

const SERVER_URL = 'http://http://ec2-54-220-173-191.us-west-
```

Comment: Possible duplicate of [nodejs EADDRINUSE error](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/28728548/nodejs-eaddrinuse-error)

Comment: lsof -i :3979 -> kill -1 pid_shown_by_previous_command and the run your app again.

Answer (score 0):

The problem was with server already running ,
Error: listen EADDRINUSE :::3979

Adding `pkill -f node` to deployment script
prior to starting node server solved the problem