# error in code while running in nodejs

Tags: node.js

```
var express = require('express'),
    app = express.createServer();

app.use(express.logger());

app.get('/', function(req, res){
    res.send('Hello World');
});

app.listen();
console.log('Express server started on port %s', app.address().port);
```

I get the error  "unexpected identifier"

what is wrong with the code?

Answer (score 0):

I don't think there's a method `createServer` in `express`. This is from their docs:

```
var express = require('express');
var app = express();

app.get('/', function(req, res){
  res.send('hello world');
});

app.listen(3000);
```

http://expressjs.com/en/starter/hello-world.html

Answer (score 0):

`express.createServer()` has been deprecated. Please check this question

[Nodejs / Express - Launching my app: express.createServer() is deprecated](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13499010/nodejs-express-launching-my-app-express-createserver-is-deprecated)

on how to update the project to work with more recent versions of express.

Comment: express.logger() as well. It should use [morgan](https://github.com/expressjs/morgan)

Answer (score 0):

You didn't declare port anywhere and also you didn't mention the port number  also.When you are using `app.address().port`it does not hold any port value so that's why it returns undefined.Here is my code hope this helps for you.Just save this code with a name I saved it as `server.js`

```
var http=require('http');
var express = require('express');
var app = express();
app.set('port', process.env.PORT || 8000);
app.get('/', function(req, res){
res.send('Hello World');
});
var server = http.createServer(app);
server.listen(app.get('port'), function(){
console.log('Express server listening on port ' + app.get('port'));
});

OUTPUT IN TERMINAL:
C:\Users\nodejs\tasks>node server.js
Express server listening on port 8000
```

Open a browser and type `localhost:8000` then

```
 OUTPUT IN BROWSER:
 Hello World
```