# why is createServer() considered not a function?

Tags: javascript, node.js, express, visual-studio-code

I installed express globally and npm installed my express app, yet neither the intellisence or the app is working ( I am using visual studio code on mac OS Yosemite).

here is a sample code:

```
/// <reference path="typings/node/node.d.ts" />
/// <reference path="typings/express/express.d.ts" />

var express = require('express');
var app = express.createServer();
app.get('/', function (req, res) {
    res.send('hi');
})

app.listen(8000);
```

and here are the errors I am getting:

```
Abeds-MacBook-Pro:myNode AZ$ node twitter.js 
/Users/AZ/Desktop/myNode/twitter.js:5
var app = express.createServer();
                  ^

TypeError: express.createServer is not a function
    at Object.<anonymous> (/Users/AZ/Desktop/myNode/twitter.js:5:19)
    at Module._compile (module.js:397:26)
    at Object.Module._extensions..js (module.js:404:10)
    at Module.load (module.js:343:32)
    at Function.Module._load (module.js:300:12)
    at Function.Module.runMain (module.js:429:10)
    at startup (node.js:139:18)
    at node.js:999:3
```

I researched a bit and found that createServer() has been deprecated. I read that I need to change the version somewhere in my application.

[image: Here is my application folder]

Note: I did another application using purely Node.js, and createServer() did work without any error along with the intellisence.

EDIT:
in my other application I used `require('net')` instead.

I modified my code to the following:

```
var express = require('express')
  , http = require('http');

    var app = express(); 
    var server = http.createServer(app);
    console.log('Listening on port 8000')
    app.get('/', function (req, res) {
        res.send('hi');
    })

    app.listen(8000)
```

The problem I have now is that `res.send('hi');` has not been reached, aka, I cannot send to the client.

EDIT 2:

I tried the following code provided in one of the answers:

```
const express = require('express');
const http = require('http');

const app = express();
const server = http.createServer(app).listen(8080, function(err) {
  if (err) {
    console.log(err);
  } else {
    const host = server.address().address;
    const port = server.address().port;
    console.log(`Server listening on ${host}:${port}`);
  }
});
app.get('/', function (req, res) {
    res.send('hi');
})
```

`res.send('hi');` still does not work, neither does it provide an error.

Comment: Not sure whether it helps, but I always use `var app = express()` instead of `var app = express.createServer()`.

Comment: @JoachimIsaksson does this create a server?

Comment: Always though of it as creating the application, but yes, it creates an object you can call `get` on just like you are doing. Just replacing the line makes your sample code run.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Nodejs / Express - Launching my app: express.createServer() is deprecated](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/13499010/nodejs-express-launching-my-app-express-createserver-is-deprecated)

Comment: @kyrylkov I tried the answers, check the edit.

Comment: There is no need for `createServer` any more, just follow the extremely simple [examples on the Express website](http://expressjs.com/en/starter/hello-world.html) and build from there.

Comment: @adeneo thank you for the link, I'll work on it starting there

Answer (score 8, accepted):

`createServer` is a function of `http` so it should be:

```
const express = require('express');
const http = require('http');

const app = express();
app.get('/', function (req, res) {
  res.send('hi');
});

const server = http.createServer(app).listen(8080, function(err) {
  if (err) {
    console.log(err);
  } else {
    const host = server.address().address;
    const port = server.address().port;
    console.log(`Server listening on ${host}:${port}`);
  }
});
```

P.S. Installing `express` globally is a bad idea

Comment: okay so the errors are gone, but I can't send to the client anything. res.send('hi'); has not been reached

Comment: What port does the server listen to?  What port are you pointing the client to?

Comment: I fixed the ports in your example, the server is supposedly up but I still cannot send

Comment: Do you still have `app.get('/', function (req, res) { res.send('hi'); })` before `http.createServer(app)`?

Comment: check the edit, I posted the edited code based on your answer

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/100854/discussion-between-kyrylkov-and-predator44).